# Unable to find template "base.html.twig" error message while deploying Symfony5/php7 app on Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, templates, heroku, twig

While deploying my Symfony5/php7.4/MariaDB application from Github to Heroku, I have this error message : "{"message":"Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\LoaderError: "Unable to find template "base.html.twig " (looked into: /app/templates, /app/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form) in "home.html.twig"
though I do have a base.html.twig file in my project in the templates folder.

What I already did and thus do not consider the reason of the failure :

- I created a procfile at the root of my projet stating web: heroku-php-apache2 public/
  which is the exact name of my file in my project that is to say public/,
- I added a .htaccess file at the root of my project thanks to the composer require apache-pack command,
- I set my config variables in Heroku with the correct addon DB url attached by Heroku, and I set  my APP_ENV as prod environement,
- I set all my bundles config in my project so that they also work in prod environment,
- I redeployed my application,
- In my dev environment, the application runs perfectly. I have in my composer.josn file an autoload psr4 strategy as below :

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

to point to the src file for the App namespace.

- All files have a correct namespace.
- My files directories names like "public", "templates" dot not contain capital letters, as I saw a similar post while doing research on SOF, stating that Linux used by heroku systems are case-sensitive. This does not seem to be my problem here.
- I even renamed my "App" namespace into  "app" namespace in every file and in my autoload psr4, as the error message mentionned "looked into: /app/templates" with no capital letter. This generated a build failed by Heroku.

Once again, this problem occured only when deploying on Heroku although  I specifically set the new environement variables for the Heroku production environement.

Has anyone any idea what the cause of this error message might be? Many thanks in advance.

PS: If you rate down this question because you find that it is unclear or useless or does not show enough research - which I did though -, please, be **specific** and add a comment to explain the reason of your negative rate, to keep this place a qualitative one and help me understand your rating.

Answer (score 0):

It finally runs well on my Heroku production environement. I did several changes. One that may explain the origin of the problem is that I used simple quotes in several templates for the extends instruction like this : "{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}, and I also noticed a blank space before ending quote in one of these templates instructions, like this : {% extends "base.html.twig " %}. I edited those instructions and replced the simple quotes by double quotes, and I erased the blank space in the template name. The application deployed correctly shortly after. This may be the answer of the Twig loading error message.

Comment: "simple quotes" are not a problem

Comment: So, I guess, the blank space I mentionned may be the problem.